# (Django) Edit db.sqlite3 database on a HTML Contenteditable table using Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, sqlite

I'm trying to create an content editable HTML table that'll update the db.sqlite3 database on keypress. The table can't have an input field in it because I also require it to be able to be filter and search using data-tables. so far I manage to retrieve the input on enter keypress but i don't know how to POST it straight to database (Presumably using AJAX) instead of JSON. Can anyone provide me with complete syntax sample as well, I'm very new to Django

Here's my code :

Model.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.a
```

form.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['a', 'b']
```

view.py

```
def display_table(request):
    context = {
        "table_list": MyModel.objects.all(),
        "title": "Table_List"
    }
    return render(request, 'tables/display.html', context)
```

display.html

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="test_post">{% csrf_token %}
                        <div id="debug" contenteditable data-name="custom-text">Some text you can edit.</div>
                        <table id="myTable" class="display">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>A</th>
                                    <th>B</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for data in table_list %}
                                    <tr >

                                        <td contenteditable="true" data-name="a_name" id="{{data.id}}">{{data.a}}</td>{% csrf_token %}
                                        <td contenteditable="true" data-name="b_name" >{{data.b}}</td>{% csrf_token %}
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>

<script>

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        var esc = event.which == 27,
          nl = event.which == 13,
          el = event.target,
          data = {};

        if (esc) {
          // restore state
          document.execCommand('undo');
          el.blur();
        } else if (nl) {
          // save
          data[el.getAttribute('data-name')] = el.innerHTML;



          // we could send an ajax request to update the field
          $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST"
          });


          log(JSON.stringify(data));

          el.blur();
          event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, true);

    function log(s) {
        document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = 'value changed to: ' + s;
        console.log(s);
    }
</script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
</script>
```

Thank you very much for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right about using AJAX. A few things you will need to modify:

**1. Your HTML/JS**

```
      $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        // include URL
        url: 'url/to/post/to',
        // include response handler here
        success: function(response) {
            // do whatever you want with response
            // you can just console.log(response.data) first
        },
        error: function(response) {
            // error handler to failed AJAX requests
        } 
      });
```

**2. Views**

You'll need to change your view to return a [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) instead of using `render` which creates an HTML response. Note that the JsonResponse will be the exact response received in the AJAX handler above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you help me with the syntax this is where I'm stuck for days because all the tutorial I found are only for using JSON file, I have no idea what to write in both ajax function and the views. I'm fairly new to python. thanks again

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve though - not sure I fully understand your objective. In essence, what you would want to do is, in your views - pass a `response` dictionary to `JsonResponse()`. Something like your `context`: remember, you want to return a JSON response, so you have to pass the data to the `JsonResponse()` function in order for it to return a JSON response.

For more details I suggest taking a look online- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: My apologies for not being clear, my objective is to send a update response directly to my 'db.sqlite3' database and not to a 'JSON file'. In other word whenever I edit the content of my HTML table and press enter it will immediately update my database, again thanks for your help

Comment: Hey no worries - in any case, you still need to return a JSON response. Bear in mind a JSON response does not equate to a JSON file. You can do your updates in your view as you would with any other view using ModelForms - if that is holding you back, I suggest you take a look at Django's docs. Basically, do the same as you would in a normal view, but change your last line to `return JsonResponse(response)` where response is a dictionary containing your response. This will be passed to the `success` function in the AJAX handler, there you can update the table using the data you've received.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a look, thanks a bunch for tips Thomas. Appreciate it. I would like to up vote your answer but unfortunately my reputation is not enough.

Comment: No worries about it happy to help. In any case you can follow the template I've provided above for the AJAX handler - just modify your views first to return JsonResponse, then go to your AJAX and try to `console.log(response.data)` or `console.log(response)` first to see what it returns in your browser's console. It might give you a better idea.